# remove column from timeLineview

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

I just created the most basic TimelineView under FullCalendar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='fr'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <link href='./fullcalendar/packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='./fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='./fullcalendar/packages-premium/timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
        
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages/core/locales/fr.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages-premium/timeline/main.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages-premium/resource-common/main.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages-premium/resource-timegrid/main.js'></script>
        <script src='./fullcalendar/packages-premium/resource-timeline/main.js'></script>

        <script src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    

    
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id='calendar'></div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey:'',
        plugins: ['resourceTimeline'  ],
        defaultView: 'resourceTimelineMonth'})
    calendar.render();  
</script>
```

The issue is that it renders a grey column in the 2nd place which I do not want
[image]

How to remove / hide this column ?

Thanks

Comment: var hideCol = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-divider fc-col-resizer fc-widget-header');
    hideCol[0].style.width = "0px";
    hideCol[1].style.width = "0px";

Dirty but it works. I am still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the resource-timeline CSS file. I can't reproduce your problem with a standard Scheduler setup. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/WNQyrzN

But if you remove that file then your problem starts to occur. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdeKVLQ

I can also see that the relevant CSS file is missing from your code shown above. In your case I expect you need a link like this:

```
<link href='./fullcalendar/packages-premium/resource-timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

The [FullCalendar plugin index](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index) shows what JS and CSS file (if any) is needed for each plugin to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks much ! Went through this list a dozen times without noticing the missing one.